# Can international student in Russia apply for tourist Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, europe, pakistani-citizens

I am student in Russia from Pakistan I am planning to go in Schengen states for tourism for 2 weeks on holidays. Can I apply for that tourist visa ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to ?

Comment: Are you a resident in Russia? Which embassy would you apply to?

Answer (score 2):

**You can apply.** The application will go to the embassy or consulate belonging to the *main destination* of your trip which is responsible for your *place of residence*. As a student in Russia, you are probably a resident of some town in Russia. If that is not the case, you are a resident some town in Pakistan.

**Your application may be denied.** The Schengen area tries to *admit all genuine tourists* and to *exclude all illegal immigrants.* Part of the decision is based on your ties to your home country and to your place of residence. As a resident in Russia, your ties to Pakistan are probably weak. As a citizen of Pakistan, your ties to Russia are probably weak.

**Your application may be granted.** If the rest of your application is strong, that can overcome weak ties to your place of residence.

Comment: Shouldn't being enrolled in a university be considered as having sufficient ties? It is probably not easy for a Pakistani to get enrolled to a Russian university. Thus, wouldn't emigrating without ever finishing that degree be considered highly unlikely?

Comment: @user4551, we get plenty of questions like *will I get a visa if ...* or *can I get a visa if ...*? It would be wrong to give probabilities without knowing all the facts, and probably not even then.